# How to pass rest of props to react component while also having required props defined in an interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So is this the same issue, or am I just missing something?

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface Props {
    value: string;
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => {
    const { value, ...rest } = props;

    return (
        <input {...rest} type="text" value={value} />
    );
}

interface ParentState {
    searchText: string;
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component<{}, ParentState> {
    state: ParentState = {
        searchText: ''
    };

    onSearchTextChanged = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        this.setState({
            searchText: e.currentTarget.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { searchText } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Some Text</h2>
                <MyComponent value={searchText} onChange={this.onSearchTextChanged} className="search-input" placeholder="Enter text"/> 
// Errors here
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ParentComponent
```

When I have my props for MyComponent defined in an interface, I get the following error:

error TS2339: Property 'onChange' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.

However if I change the props type to any, it compiles just fine.

```
const MyComponent = (props: any) => {
```

Is it possible to define the props in an interface so that there are specific props that are required, but also allow additional props to be passed in so I don't have to explicitly add them into the interface?

I'm using TypeScript 2.3.4 and React 15.5.4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can avoid excess property/attribute checks by adding a *string index signature* to your interface:

```
interface Props {
    value: string;

    // This is a string index signature.
    // This means that all properties in 'Props' are assignable to
    // the empty object type ({})
    [propName: string]: {};
}
```

You could also write `[propName: string]: any` but that generally makes it less safe to use in `MyComponent` itself.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to forward all properties of the `input` element inside `MyComponent` to the props of `MyComponent` you can lookup what props `input` (in VSCode for example, use go to definition while on the `input` tag).

```
interface IntrinsicElements {
   ....
   input: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<>, HTMLInputElement>;
   ....
}
```

We could use `React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>` as the base type  for our props and we will get all properties of `input`. Since DetailedHTMLProps just adds `ref` to `React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>` we can use just `React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>` as the base interface to get all `input` properties except the `ref`:

```
import * as React from 'react'

interface Props extends React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
    value: string;
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => {
    const { value, ...rest } = props;

    return (
        <input {...rest} type="text" value={value} />
    );
}

// Usage
interface ParentState  { searchText :string }
class ParentComponent extends React.Component<{}, ParentState> {
  state: ParentState = {
      searchText: ''
  };

  onSearchTextChanged = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      this.setState({
          searchText: e.currentTarget.value
      });
  }

  render() {
      const { searchText } = this.state;

      return (
          <div>
              <h2>Some Text</h2>
              <MyComponent value={searchText} onChange={this.onSearchTextChanged} className="search-input" placeholder="Enter text"/> 
          </div>
      )
  }
}

export default ParentComponent
```