# Specify specific props and accept general HTML props in Typescript React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have a React Wrapper Component, that accepts some props, but forwards all others to the child component (especially relevent for native props like className, id, etc.).

Typescript complains, however, when I pass native props. See error message:

> TS2339: Property 'className' does not exist on type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes< Wrapper > & Readonly< {
>   children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly< WrapperProps>'.

**How can I get a component with specific props that also accepts native props (*without* accepting any props and giving up on type checking)?**

My code looks like this:

```
interface WrapperProps extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes {
  callback?: Function
}

export class Wrapper extends React.Component<WrapperProps>{
  render() {
    const { callback, children, ...rest } = this.props;
    return <div {...rest}>
      {children}
    </div>;
  }
}

export const Test = () => {
  return <Wrapper className="test">Hi there</Wrapper>
}
```

FYI: I found a similar question here, but the answer basically gives up type checking, which I want to avoid: [Link to SO-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44349409/9430509)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

We can have a look at how `div` props are defined:

```
interface IntrinsicElements {
    div: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>;
}
```

If we use `React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>` as the base type we will have all properties of `div`. Since `DetailedHTMLProps` just adds `ref` to `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>` we can use just this as the base interface to get all `div` properties:

```
interface WrapperProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  callback?: Function
}

export class Wrapper extends React.Component<WrapperProps>{
  render() {
    const { callback, children, ...rest } = this.props;
    return <div {...rest}>
      {children}
    </div>;
  }
}

export const Test = () => {
  return <Wrapper className="test">Hi there</Wrapper> // works now
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
This seems a bit verbose. Is there no other "more react" or "more typescript" way to do that? It seems like a pretty usual use-case and extending the HTMLBaseAttributes seems a bit overkill.
But the answer solves the question, so thanks!

Comment: @SergejHerbert I meant to remove the `DetailedHTMLProps` part, removed it now. This is the shortest most typescript way to do it as far as I know :)

Comment: @SergejHerbert An alternative would be to use an intersection type for the props : `class Wrapper  extends React.Component<WrapperProps & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>`

Comment: How would you do accomplish this if the native element rendered by your component is determined via a prop: `function MyComponent({ elementName: Component, children, ...props }) { return (<Component {...props}>{children}</Component>); }` since a type param is required?

Comment: @webbower I've had a similar issue and for a generic HTML element, I've used: `interface WrapperProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>`

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at `ComponentProps`, `ComponentPropsWithRef`, and `ComponentPropsWithoutRef` - this will accept a generic input that can be `"div"`, `"button"`, or any other component. It will include react specific props such as `className` as well:

```
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  ComponentPropsWithoutRef,
  ComponentProps,
  ComponentPropsWithRef
} from "react";

const ExampleDivComponent = forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"div">
>(({ children, ...props }, ref) => {
  return (
    <div {...props} ref={ref}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
});

<ExampleDivComponent
  className=""
  style={{ background: "green" }}
  tabIndex={0}
  onTouchStart={() => alert("touched")}
/>;

const ExampleButtonComponent: React.FC<ComponentProps<"button">> = ({
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  return <button {...props}>{children}</button>;
};

<ExampleButtonComponent onClick={() => alert("clicked")} />;
```

Comment: Yes, looks as `ComponentProps` is the proper way to go there. `interface Props extends ComponentProps<'div'> {...`

Answer (score 8):

JSX.IntrinsicElements has this info, e.g.

```
const FooButton: React.FC<JSX.IntrinsicElements['button']> = props => (
  <button {...props} className={`foo ${props.className}`} />
)

// alternative...
const FooButton: React.FC<React.PropsWithoutRef<
  JSX.IntrinsicElements['button']
>> = props => <button {...props} className={`foo ${props.className}`} />
```

discovered this in the [react-typescript-cheatsheet](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#useful-react-prop-type-examples) project.

Answer (score 2):

A co-worker of mine figured it out. Sharing here for broader visibility:

```
interface ComponentPropTypes = {
  elementName?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements; // list of all native DOM components
  ...
}


// Function component
function Component({
  elementName: Component = 'div',
  ...rest,
  // React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>) provides all possible native DOM attributes
}: ComponentPropTypes & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>)): JSX.Element {
  return <Component {...rest} />;
}

// Class component
class Component extends React.Component<ComponentPropTypes & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>> {
  render() {
    const {
      elementName: Component,
      ...rest,
    } = this.props;
    return <Component {...rest} />
  }
}
```