# Typescript: extending properties of div element fails on react ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-beautiful-dnd

I am working on a Drag and Drop scenario with react-beautiful-dnd, trying to add a drop animation, following the manual https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/guides/drop-animation.md.

Using typescript I am getting in trouble when I add a `isDragging` property to a simple div element. Trying to work around this problem I was building a component with extended properties, following

[Specify specific props and accept general HTML props in Typescript React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51835611/specify-specific-props-and-accept-general-html-props-in-typescript-react-app)

This worked to some point, but is failing on the ref property.

My code:

```
interface IdragDiv extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, React.RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  isDragging: boolean;
}
export class DragDiv extends React.Component<IdragDiv> {
  render() {
    const { children, ...rest } = this.props;
    return <div {...rest}>{children}</div>;
  }
}
```

Calling it like this:

```
...
          return (
            <Draggable
              draggableId={...}
            >
              {(provided, snapshot) => {
                return (
                  <DragDiv
                    {...className}
                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                    {...provided!.draggableProps}
                    {...provided!.dragHandleProps}
                    isDragging={snapshot.isDragging && !snapshot.isDropAnimating}
                  >
                    ...
                  </DragDiv>
                );
              }}
            </Draggable>
          );
...
```

This results in following error:

```
(property) ref?: (string & ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void)) | (string & React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>) | (((instance: DragDiv | null) => void) & ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void)) | ... 4 more ... | undefined

No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<IdragDiv>): DragDiv', gave the following error.
    Type '(element?: HTMLElement | null | undefined) => any' is not assignable to type '(string & ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void)) | (string & RefObject<HTMLDivElement>) | (((instance: DragDiv | null) => void) & ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void)) | ... 4 more ... | undefined'.
      Type '(element?: HTMLElement | null | undefined) => any' is not assignable to type 'string & ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void)'.
        Type '(element?: HTMLElement | null | undefined) => any' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: IdragDiv, context?: any): DragDiv', gave the following error.
    Type '(element?: HTMLElement | null | undefined) => any' is not assignable to type '(string & ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void)) | (string & RefObject<HTMLDivElement>) | (((instance: DragDiv | null) => void) & ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void)) | ... 4 more ... | undefined'.
      Type '(element?: HTMLElement | null | undefined) => any' is not assignable to type 'string & ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void)'.
        Type '(element?: HTMLElement | null | undefined) => any' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Any ideas, is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to use createRef() in your code like this:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  private myRef = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />
  }
}
```

This is simplified ofc, but that should fix the error you are encountering.

Possibly this will fix it for react-beautiful-dnd then, by creating your own ref prop for the DragDiv you have:

```
class DragDiv extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div {...this.props} ref={this.props.innerRef}></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then in your Draggable:

```
return (
  <Draggable draggableId={...}>
    {(provided, snapshot) => {
      return (
        <DragDiv
          {...className}
          innerRef={provided.innerRef}
          ...
```

See if that fixes it for you.

Comment: Not in this scenario. The ref is provided by react-beautiful-dnd and must be called like I did. ref={provided.innerRef}

Comment: Updated the answer @smaug333 see if that can help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is not how to add a ref to an element. Problem here is to find the right typing. I was trying to add a property "isDragging", which is not known by react/typescript. 
Skipping typescript my code would doubtlessly work fine

Comment: Maybe instead of HTMLDivElement you should try HTMLElement - the error you are experiencing seems to focus on that. Also that error is pointing at ref being the issue, not isDragging.

Comment: The isDragging Problem was already solved. It must be  a HTMLDivElement, only HTMLElement leads to errors in the DragDiv-Definition.